# Starting a new activity and closing the current one with clear top flag in not working

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

Am inside an activity which uses a **StringRequest** for **Volley**

when I receive a response from the server inside the **onResponse** method

I want to close the current activity and start a new one

the problem is after I receive the response , the new activity starts

but if I hit the back button I go back to the previous activity that should be closed

here is what I'm doing

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();

                        Log.e("spool",response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject json=new JSONObject(response);

                            if(json.getInt(LoginActivity.TAG_SUCCESS)==1)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,json.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,json.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },....
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `finish()` call after `startActivity(intent);`

Also, not a good idea to display a `Toast` message if you are starting a new activity right after. The `Toast` message would be visible only for a few milliseconds.

Comment: thanks it worked, even I could swear that I read somewhere that finish() will not be called after startActivity(..); ,,,, but is there a way to display the Toast here or I just have to pass the message inside the intent and show it in the new activity?

Comment: Yes. Either you use an application context for the toast, or the new activity receives the String and toats's it.

Comment: @RobertEstivill your answer help me lot :)